# Issue with Thymeleaf th:href, the link seems not to be created and thus not clickable

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, href

I have a simple html page, "index.html". I'm testing `server.servlet.context-path=/test` and i'm testing on the webpage the redirection on itself, nothing more. For some reason that I can't understand, even with the docs about thymeleaf `https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html`

```
<a th:href="@{/index.html}">Reload page</a>
```

It's just displaying "Reload page" and I can't even click on it. My goal is to be able to click on it and to be redirected to /test/index.html, as I thought this would be the accurate method.

Feel free to give me any advice on how to do so, or why isn't it working the way it's supposed to be.

Thanks you very much for your time !

EDIT : Here are the dependencies thymeleaf-related I'm using :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<head> 
<title>Test page</title> 
</head> 
<body>

   <a th:href=@{/index.html}>Reload page</a>


</body> 
</html>
```

This is the exact page I'm using. If I remove the xmlns in the html tag, the th:ref is marked as "Undefined attribute name (th:href)." Which made me think that when I have the xmlns (as it is right now) the attribute is correctly defined.

Comment: View the source in the browser and verify that `th:href` is being interpreted as `href`.

Comment: @Metroids Thank you for your answer, when I use F12 to see the inspector, I can see that the th:href IS NOT interpreted as href. I know this is an issue but i don't know how to solve it. I successfully have thymeleaf on my webpage since he "knows" th:href

Comment: If you can see `th:href`, it means your Thymeleaf is not being interpreted.  You have to correctly configure Thymeleaf to run your templates. (Without knowing what your configuration looks like, it's not possible to debug this.)

Comment: Start with the basics: (1) Where have you placed your `index.html` template? Spring Boot, by default, expects to find it in `src/main/resources/templates`. (2) How are you rendering this template? Show us the relevant Spring controller code. (3) Ideally, please provide a [mre].

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I add some extra informations.
(1) My 'index.html' is in the src/main/resources/static, but I told Spring to look in this location.
(2) I actually don't have any controller for this, or more likely I can't find it (I'm working on a project which is not mine, it's quite messy and I can't find which controller renders the "index.html" page...
(3) I hope the minimal reproducible example I edited is enough ! Thanks you again

Comment: Thymeleaf templates should not be placed in `static`. How do you know what URL to use if you can't find the controller?